# Optimize many subqueries with same source

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone have any idea how to optimize such a query?
How do you encapsulate this into one query?

```
,(SELECT top 1 WFD_AttDecimal2 as Nocleg
            FROM   WFElements INNER JOIN
             WFElementDetails ON WFElements.WFD_ID = WFElementDetails.DET_WFDID
             Where 
             WFD_STPID = @KrokSlownikUdostepnionyKraj 
             and dbo.ClearWFElemID (WFD_AttChoose20) = KrajDoDiety6 -- id kraju
             and dbo.ClearWFElemID (WFD_AttChoose9) = @Spolka) as NoclegStawka7
,(SELECT top 1 WFD_AttDecimal3 as NoclegPrzelicznik
            FROM   WFElements INNER JOIN
             WFElementDetails ON WFElements.WFD_ID = WFElementDetails.DET_WFDID
             Where 
             WFD_STPID = @KrokSlownikUdostepnionyKraj 
             and dbo.ClearWFElemID (WFD_AttChoose20) = KrajDoDiety6 -- id kraju
             and dbo.ClearWFElemID (WFD_AttChoose9) = @Spolka) as NoclegPrzelicznik7
,PelneDoby6 * (select  MinDieta from @MinDieta where RodzajDelegacji = KrajZagr6) as MinIloscDiet7
from @Dieta4
```

Comment: I have several more subqueries with the same source after from

Comment: Those subqueries have a "Code Smell" to them; they have a `TOP (1)` but no `ORDER BY`. A `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY` and select all the necessary columns within that, you can then access all of them in the `SELECT`

```sql
SELECT 
  wfd.Nocleg as NoclegStawka7
, wfd.NoclegPrzelicznik as NoclegPrzelicznik7
, d.PelneDoby6 * (select md.MinDieta from @MinDieta md where RodzajDelegacji = KrajZagr6) as MinIloscDiet7
from @Dieta4 d
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      WFD_AttDecimal2 as Nocleg,
      WFD_AttDecimal3 as NoclegPrzelicznik
    FROM   WFElements INNER JOIN
      WFElementDetails ON WFElements.WFD_ID = WFElementDetails.DET_WFDID
    Where 
      WFD_STPID = @KrokSlownikUdostepnionyKraj 
      and dbo.ClearWFElemID (WFD_AttChoose20) = KrajDoDiety6 -- id kraju
      and dbo.ClearWFElemID (WFD_AttChoose9) = @Spolka
) wfd;
```

Note also:

- I suggest you rethink your usage of a scalar function `ClearWFElemID` as it can be slow. Use a join or a Table Valued function instead.
- `TOP (1)` without an `ORDER BY` is a code-smell: you may get a different result each time.
- Always specify the table alias when using subqueries, or you risk getting the wrong results.

Comment: if I have two other subqueries in the same query can I add another outer apply?

Comment: @RadosławBegej Yes you can, but note that it works like a join but per outer row: if for that outer row the inner subquery returns multiple rows then you get duplicate outer rows. Also `OUTER` works like a left-join and `CROSS` works like an inner-join